# Am i at the end of a list ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

In ColdFusion how do I tell if I'm at the end of a list. I know about `listLast`, but this just returns the last data in the list. I want to know when the list has finished. I need to know this so i can change a string accordingly.

ie. mystring = product with list1, list2 and listlast

Its so i know when to add the "and" to my output.

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listLen()` will give you the total of items. Then as you loop through the list check if you've reach `listLen()`

Comment: Thanks! I'm using listLen already, not sure why I never thought of it!
Early morning, late nights!

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`ListLen(list [, delimiters ])`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d6c.html)? It returns the number of elements in a list.

```
<cfscript>
  var i = 1;
  var listLength = ListLen(mystring);

  for (i = 1; i lte listLength; i++)
  {
    product = ListGetAt(mystring, i);
  }
</cfscript>
```

Here's a reference of other [List Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a42).

Comment: Thank you, I have answered "twitter cfdatabase" as correct and moved yours up a vote. Done on a first answer basis as both are correct!

Comment: I must be being thick here or just knackered! So i have a list jason,jill,john i want to output this in a single string like this In the room was Jason, John and Jill. How do I pick out the individual parts of the list and output it? If i loop around the list using cfloop how do i know what is first second and last, bearing in mind the list may be larger? Sorry but never used lists to create readable strings before. Help is greatly appreciated?

Comment: `var i = 1; l = ListLen(names); for (i = 1; i lte l; i++){ name }

Answer (score 2):

@Jason Congerton
use index="i" (or anything) and output in the list using #i#

You could also use

`<cfloop from="1" to="listlen(yourlist)#" index="i">`

`Number #i# #ListGetAt(yourList, i)#<br>`

`</cfloop>`

i gives you the placement in the list and the ListGetAt() function pulls out the value in that place in the list. This will work if your list is 1 or 10,000 names.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you response this code has helped me out, i have one slight issue. My string is now formatted to "product with listpart1, listpart2" i now need to finsh it with listpart1, listpart2, and lastlistpart. In other words i need to say if this is the last bit in the list do not put a comma put and. My code is below;
`<cfloop from="1" to="#myLen#" index="i">
<cfif i EQ 1><cfset myH1 = "with "><cfset myH1 = myH1 & listGetAt(session[h1Session], i)></cfif>
<cfif i GT 1><cfset myH1 = myH1 & ", " & listGetAt(session[h1Session], i)></cfif>
</cfloop>`

Comment: I've got it!!!!
`<cfif i GT 1>
<cfif i EQ myLen>
<cfset myH1 = myH1 & " and " & listGetAt(session[h1Session], i)><cfelse>
<cfset myH1 = myH1 & ", " & listGetAt(session[h1Session], i)></cfif>`

Thank you very much, i have voted up on this one!

Answer (score 0):

CF function list.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_13.html

specifically, look at ListLast() function.

The last user in the list is: ListLast(temp)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing that requires you to know the last element of the list but you can also just use cfloop list =

```
<cfset myList = "me,myself,i">
<cfoutput>
<cfloop list = "#myList#" index = "i">
#i#
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```